# Trigger impede alteração da tabela

Tags: oracle, pl-sql, trigger

Preciso de fazer um trigger que impeça que, no mesmo dia, o mesmo funcionário possa fazer parte de mais de uma tripulação.

A tabela tripulação é a seguinte:

```
Tripulação = {id_Voo, data, id_Funcionário }
```

Os 3 atributos são em conjunto a chave primária.

O que eu quero fazer aqui é ver se já existe numa mesma fila da tabela `Tripulação` o `:new.id_Funcionário` e `:new.data`.

Comment: Acredito que basta definir esses dois campos como `Unique` para resolver o problema. Não precisa de trigger.

Comment: @Earendul é para trabalho académico

Comment: Essa solução não te serve? http://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/21270418/Check-if-exists-trigger.html#a13018305

Comment: É preciso criar conta para ver essa resposta.

Comment: É mesmo, antes eu conseguia ver, agora já não consigo mais :(

Answer (score 1):

A trigger ficaria assim.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER NOME_DA_TRIGGER
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON TRIPULACAO
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
V_JAEXISTE NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT 1 INTO V_JAEXISTE FROM TRIPULACAO T WHERE T.ID_FUNCIONARIO = :NEW.ID_FUNCIONARIO AND T.DATA = :NEW.DATA;

  IF V_JAEXISTE = 1 THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (
         num => 1234,
         msg => 'Mensagem de erro');
   END IF;
END;
```

Mas realmente a melhor alternativa seria uma UNIQUE KEY composta por essas duas colunas.